# unable to locate package ros-hydro-rviz

Tags: rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I'm a bleeding raw beginner with ROS so please tread gently. I am trying to install the package ros-hydro-rviz using this command *sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz*  but am getting the message that it cannot be located.

My OS is Ubuntu Xenial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261224/unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-rviz/) by [Elle_Idan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30288/elle_idan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot install Hydro packages on a ROS Kinetic install.

Try `ros-kinetic-rviz`.

But depending on how you installed ROS that package will have already been installed for you (as part of the `ros-kinetic-desktop` or `ros-kinetic-desktop-full`).

See [REP 3 - Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and [REP 142 - ROS Indigo and Newer Metapackages](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html) for reference.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elle_Idan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30288/elle_idan/) on 2017-05-07**:
Thanks, it looks like it is already installed.

Onto resolving the next problem: Cannot connect to ROS Master....